# ld: library not found for -lDoubleConversion clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) in Xcode

Tags: xcode, react-native

I am developing a react native app. When I build the project in Xcode, the build failed, and here is the error:

```
Ld /Users/nitieii/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BiceUser-dedbblwkymtlkzciefxyqepnavct/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/BiceUser.app/BiceUser normal (in target 'BiceUser' from project 'BiceUser')
    cd /Users/nitieii/Desktop/BiceUserAppProject/ios
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -target x86_64-apple-ios10.0-simulator -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.5.sdk -L/Users/nitieii/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BiceUser-dedbblwkymtlkzciefxyqepnavct/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/nitieii/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BiceUser-dedbblwkymtlkzciefxyqepnavct/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/nitieii/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BiceUser-dedbblwkymtlkzciefxyqepnavct/Build/Intermediates.noindex/BiceUser.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BiceUser.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/BiceUser.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /usr/lib/swift -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/nitieii/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BiceUser-dedbblwkymtlkzciefxyqepnavct/Build/Intermediates.noindex/BiceUser.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BiceUser.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/BiceUser_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -ObjC -lDoubleConversion -lFBReactNativeSpec -lPermission-Camera -lRCT-Folly -lRCTTypeSafety -lRNAWSCognito -lRNCAsyncStorage -lRNCCheckbox -lRNGestureHandler -lRNImageCropPicker -lRNPermissions -lRNSVG -lRNScreens -lRNVectorIcons -lReact-Core -lReact-CoreModules -lReact-RCTAnimation -lReact-RCTBlob -lReact-RCTImage -lReact-RCTLinking -lReact-RCTNetwork -lReact-RCTSettings -lReact-RCTText -lReact-RCTVibration -lReact-cxxreact -lReact-jsi -lReact-jsiexecutor -lReact-jsinspector -lReact-perflogger -lReactCommon -lTOCropViewController -lYoga -lglog -lreact-native-camera -lreact-native-image-picker -lreact-native-netinfo -lreact-native-safe-area-context -lstdc++ -framework AudioToolbox -framework JavaScriptCore -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Photos -ObjC -lc++ -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/nitieii/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BiceUser-dedbblwkymtlkzciefxyqepnavct/Build/Intermediates.noindex/BiceUser.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BiceUser.build/BiceUser.app-Simulated.xcent -lPods-BiceUser -Xlinker -no_adhoc_codesign -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/nitieii/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BiceUser-dedbblwkymtlkzciefxyqepnavct/Build/Intermediates.noindex/BiceUser.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BiceUser.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/BiceUser_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/nitieii/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BiceUser-dedbblwkymtlkzciefxyqepnavct/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/BiceUser.app/BiceUser

ld: library not found for -lDoubleConversion
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

So I post this question to ask how to solve this issue and what is the main reason for this error. Thank you so much!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to delete your DerivedData project folder:

'Xcode' -> 'Preferences' -> 'Locations' tab -> At 'Derived Data' click the open icon and delete the folder in Finder.

Then Clean build folder. Also make sure you have xcworkspace open not xcproject and also try pod deintegrate and pod install prior to this from inside the iOS dir of the project.